# Understanding xarray groupby

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to count the number of members in each group, akin to `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.count`. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Here is an example:

```
In [1]: xr_test = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(6), coords=[[10,10,11,12,12,12]], dims=['dim0'])
        xr_test
Out[1]: <xarray.DataArray (dim0: 6)>
        array([ 0.92908804,  0.15495709,  0.85304435,  0.24039265,  0.3755476 ,
                0.29261274])
        Coordinates:
          * dim0     (dim0) int32 10 10 11 12 12 12

In [2]: xr_test.groupby('dim0').count()
Out[2]: <xarray.DataArray (dim0: 6)>
        array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
        Coordinates:
          * dim0     (dim0) int32 10 10 11 12 12 12
```

However, I expect this output:

```
Out[2]: <xarray.DataArray (dim0: 3)>
        array([2, 1, 3])
        Coordinates:
          * dim0     (dim0) int32 10 11 12
```

What's going on?

In other words:

```
In [3]: xr_test.to_series().groupby(level=0).count()
Out[3]: dim0
        10    2
        11    1
        12    3
        dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug! Xarray currently makes the (in this case mistaken) assumption that coordinates corresponding to dimensions have all unique values. This usually a good idea, but shouldn't be required. If you make another coordinate this should work properly, e.g.,

`xr_test = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(6), coords={'aux': ('x', [10,10,11,12,12,12])}, dims=['x'])
xr_test.groupby('aux').count()`

Comment: Do you want me to open an issue in xarray git about this?

Comment: Also, I have already created the array in another piece of code and it looks exactly like what I have in my example above: `xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(6), coords=[[10,10,11,12,12,12]], dims=['dim0'])`. Now this other code is quite long-winded and takes a few days to run. Therefore, rerunning that being out of the question, how can I coerce my existing array to have a new coordinate? I mean what is the best way?

Comment: I also cannot find a way to access the indexes in `'aux'`. It is important for me to access those at all times. How can I access them? Thanks for your help with this @Stephan.

Comment: Take a look at the swap_dims method for switching coordinates that correspond to dimensions. An issue on the github tracker would also be great! (I'm currently on vacation and typing this on my phone.)